# Why didn't everyone blown into space from Thor's ship freeze as Ebony Maw did?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Why didn't everyone who got blown into space from Thor's ship freeze within seconds like Ebony Maw did?

Comment: The Æsir are a hardy race.

Comment: We only see one person after they're blown into space from Thor's ship, and that's Thor. If Frost Giants can't freeze him, the cold of space is as a mere lukewarm bath.

Comment: Ebony Maw isn't Æsir.

Comment: Ebony Maw isn't Human either ~ comparing his body & it's responses to physical conditions to those of ours or the Æsir may not make any sense.

Comment: Although according to Tony Stark he may be some sort of squid/octopus.

Comment: Could everyone stop saying Æsir, it really makes us look pretentious.

Answer (score 7):

We can assume that everyone visible on the ship is Asgardian and while they aren't all gods like Thor we can assume that they probably have some similar physical traits to him. As Paul D. Waite commented (I'm new to StackExchange so I don't know how to tag yet) in the first Thor movie we see several Asgardians who may be heroes but are not gods themselves fighting frost giants on Jotunheim which is probably incredibly cold, implying they have inhuman resistance to elements.

Going by that assumption when we see Thor not frozen drifting in space later in the movie, we can make the assumption that he didn't immediately freeze because he is Asgardian.

Although the fact that he's still alive after being adrift for an extended period of time with no breathable air I would attribute to his god status. Especially since the rest of the Asgardians that didn't escape were all dead.

Comment: If you accept [Marvels Agents of Shield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agents_of_S.H.I.E.L.D.) as canon (which you may not of course?) then I can confirm that yes, all the way down to the bog standard Asgardian peasant they do apparently share lifespan & physical attributes of both strength & "resilience" to physical trauma with those Asgardian heroes we're more familiar with as what would appear to be part of their basic racial traits ~ there may be other reference to this subject elsewhere of course, but that's the one I know of.

Comment: ^ I am of course referring to the Berserker Staff story arc & the character Elliot Randolph found in that story-line, starting with [The Well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Well_(Agents_of_S.H.I.E.L.D.)) (the eighth episode of the first season).

Comment: Can I just add that I love seeing Peter MacNicol as Elliot Randolph? He's a great actor and it's fun seeing Num3rs actors superheros. Now if only we can get David Krumholtz as Bruce Banner!